# Number of columns according to screen size - with fluid column width

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, responsive-design

I got my wires crossed here. I can't figure out how to get started: 
My layout should have an amount of columns according to the screen size.
There should be some break points on where the number of columns change:
E.g.:

- 4 columns below 1200 px
- 3 columns below 1024 px
- 2 columns below 900 px
- 1 column below 640 px

Between these break points, the columns should be 100% width, so that the screen is always filled (Responsive).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Greetings
Sebastian

Comment: how about using media queries to simply change the size of columns according to screen size…?

Comment: worth reading --- http://www.stephanboyer.com/post/41/fluid-responsive-grid-layouts-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for changing layout based on screen size..  for e.g:

HTML

```
<div class='box'></div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:24%;
  height:100px;
  background:purple;
}
@media screen and(max-width:1024px){
  .box{
    width:32%;
  }
}
@media screen and(max-width:900px){
  .box{
    width:49%;
  }
}
@media screen and(max-width:640px){
  .box{
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/65t8p/)

More Reading:

- [Media Queries @ w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)
- [MEdia Queries @ CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!
but is there a way to handle the number of columns according to the screen resolution?

Comment: yes, you can target the columns to hide and simply apply `display:none` inside media query...

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS media queries is what you are looking for:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  element#id {
    property: value;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  element#id {
    property: value;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  element#id {
    property: value;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  element#id {
    property: value;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try these javascript methods [Window Screen](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp)

Comment: this should be a comment since it's link only and it does not solve the problem by itself...